# jelly bean app gets killed on a phone call

Tags: android, crash

Our app is crashing on jelly bean phones (not all of them) and we are completely clueless. It can be repeated by taking a phone call, there is nothing (no exception or jni crash within our code) in logcat just:

```
03-07 13:07:33.506: I/WindowState(1660): WIN DEATH: Window{4115b0c0 com.mapfactor.navigator/com.mapfactor.navigator.map.MapActivity paused=false}
03-07 13:07:33.506: W/InputDispatcher(1660): channel '4115b0c0 com.mapfactor.navigator/com.mapfactor.navigator.map.MapActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
03-07 13:07:33.506: I/ActivityManager(1660): Process com.mapfactor.navigator (pid 3248) has died.
03-07 13:07:33.506: E/InputDispatcher(1660): channel '4115b0c0 com.mapfactor.navigator/com.mapfactor.navigator.map.MapActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
03-07 13:07:33.506: W/InputDispatcher(1660): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '4115b0c0 com.mapfactor.navigator/com.mapfactor.navigator.map.MapActivity (server)'
03-07 13:07:33.506: W/WindowManager(1660): Force-removing child win Window{40f34610 SurfaceView paused=false} from container Window{4115b0c0 com.mapfactor.navigator/com.mapfactor.navigator.map.MapActivity paused=false}
03-07 13:07:33.506: I/LocationManagerService(1660): remove gps (pid 1660), disabled
03-07 13:07:33.506: I/LocationManagerService(1660): remove network (pid 1660), next minTime = 86400000
03-07 13:07:33.506: W/GpsLocationProvider(1660): Unneeded remove listener for uid 1000
...
03-07 13:07:33.506: W/WindowManager(1660): Failed looking up window
03-07 13:07:33.506: W/WindowManager(1660): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@40e2e780 does not exist
03-07 13:07:33.506: W/WindowManager(1660):  at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7675)
03-07 13:07:33.506: W/WindowManager(1660):  at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7666)
03-07 13:07:33.506: W/WindowManager(1660):  at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:854)
03-07 13:07:33.506: W/WindowManager(1660):  at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:449)
03-07 13:07:33.506: W/WindowManager(1660):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
03-07 13:07:33.506: I/WindowState(1660): WIN DEATH: null
03-07 13:07:33.506: I/WindowManager(1660): WINDOW DIED Window{4115b0c0 com.mapfactor.navigator/com.mapfactor.navigator.map.MapActivity paused=false}
```

Comment: Step through your onPause and onStop code.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: Have you disabled `"Don't keep activities", "Destroy every activity as soon as the user leaves it"` in your *Settings > Developer Options* screen?

Comment: Whether he did or not, it shouldn't crash.

Comment: @323go Well it's a developer option. You always have the risk of quirky behaviour if enabling those.

Comment: You don't seem to understand these options. They simply accelerate what may happen in a production environment anyway, for example, due to low-memory conditions. They are specifically added to enable the developer to debug their code for those conditions. Disabling them will only hide the problem, and then have very unhappy customers down the line.

Answer (score 0):

## OutOfMemory

Possible, but not likely looking at your logcat.

Just throwing this suggestion in the air: Based on the first line, are you not stopping consuming expensive resources like GPS? Are you doing something weird with your pause code?

## IOError

So seems like an IOError (unsure why IOException wasn't raised instead) based on line 2 and line 5 here.